# Чтение из памяти за границей буфера

Tags: windows, ассемблер, memory

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь сделать некий аналог base64 энкодера на ассемблере, и возникл такой вопрос:
в алгоритме заложено преобразование трёх байт в четыре, однако на практике это означает что придётся либо читать по одному байту, либо читать два, потом ещё один, либо читать сразу четыре, а потом обрабатывать только три.

**Вопрос:** если есть некая выделенная область памяти, то безопасно ли прочитать *один* байт после неё, если мы точно знаем что его значение нам не важно и будет проигнорировано?.. Могут ли быть ситуации, когда это приведёт к AV, при условии что все данные до него - валидны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> если есть некая выделенная область памяти, то безопасно ли прочитать один байт после неё

Нет.

Что касается чтения для b64 - реализаций кодирования навалом, посмотрите как это делается. Никаких "лишних" чтений не нужно, всё решается.

Comment: Да как решается понятно, мысль была в оптимизации.

Comment: Оптимизировать надо пр результатам прогонов в профайлере. Premature optimization is the root of all evil (C).

Comment: Если хочется оптимизации такой - выделяйте буфер сразу с запасом. Тогда без проблем можно  будет читать "как бы за пределами буфера" (на самом деле все будет в пределах). Думаю, что можно смело +4 байта делать.

Comment: @KoVadim, это при условии что мы копируем в этот буфер приходящие данные.

Comment: А никто не обещал, что будет просто.

Comment: @KoVadim это при условии, что выделять буфер буду я...